# change port in wso2 sample

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am executing sample programm of wso2. I have installed wso2is on different machine and tomcat is on local machine. I have changed localhost:9443 to my ipaddress(eg 192.168.1.xxx) from travelocity.properties and avi.properties. But when I execute sample from click on login button it always redirecting me localhost and giving error.

Comment: Can you please specify more details on question? Such as, Where do you see the error? What do you have as the browser URL when you see this error? Do you have any error logs in tomcat or IS? Please try to give much as possible information, since it will helpful to narrow down the issue. Reason is, both Chamila's and Farasath's answers can be correct, but it cannot exactly tell which one would be the correct answer due to the lack of the information you provided in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to try the following,

While the tomcat is running,

1. Open the travelocity.war with an archive manager
2. Edit the travelocity.properties file,
   update SAML2.IdPURL value 
   eg : SAML2.IdPURL=https://192.168.1.7:9443/samlsso
3. Save and update the travelocity.com web app
4. Restart the tomcat server just to be sure (You don't really have to do this since tomcat hot deploys once it detects a change)

I tried this locally and it redirected me to the IP address I put in SAML2.IdpURL. Clearly the problem seems to be a configuration error on the travelocity.com web app side :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `<HostName>` and `<MgtHostName>` attributes at `repository/conf/carbon.xml` of your Identity Server with your IP address. By default they are set as localhost, so when logging it will be redirected to location specified there.

Comment: how I can change, it's running on docker contianer with docker image and I downloaded docker image from internet